# How to combine different API from microsoft cognitive services

Tags: java, android, azure, android-studio, mobile-development

I'm a novice in Android Development, how do I combine different APIs in Microsoft azure cognitive services? specifically with Face, Computer Vision, and Emotion API.

**EDIT:** Here is what I came up with, I was able to display the simple description of the image. However, I am having a hard time merging the celebrity model to my project. 
Below is process method

```
 private String process() throws VisionServiceException, IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String model = "celebrities";

    //put image into an input stream for detection
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());

    AnalysisResult v = this.client.describe(inputStream, 1);
    AnalysisInDomainResult m = this.client.analyzeImageInDomain(inputStream,model);

    String result = gson.toJson(v);
    String result2 = gson.toJson(m);

    Map map = new HashMap();

    map.put(result, result);
    map.put(result2, result2);

    return String.valueOf(map);

}
```

Here is the onPostExecute()...

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
    super.onPostExecute(data);

    mEditText.setText("");
    if (e != null) {
        mEditText.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        this.e = null;
    } else {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        AnalysisResult result = gson.fromJson(data, AnalysisResult.class);
        AnalysisInDomainResult result2 = gson.fromJson(data, AnalysisInDomainResult.class);

        //decode the returned result
        JsonArray detectedCelebs = result2.result.get("celebrities").getAsJsonArray();
        if(result2.result != null){
           mEditText.append("Celebrities detected: "+ detectedCelebs.size()+"\n");

            for(JsonElement celebElement: detectedCelebs) {
                JsonObject celeb = celebElement.getAsJsonObject();
                mEditText.append("Name: "+celeb.get("name").getAsString() +", score" +
                        celeb.get("confidence").getAsString() +"\n");
            }
        }else {
            for (Caption caption: result.description.captions) {
                mEditText.append("Your seeing " + caption.text + ", confidence: " + caption.confidence + "\n");
            }
            mEditText.append("\n");
        }


       /* for (String tag: result.description.tags) {
            mEditText.append("Tag: " + tag + "\n");
        }
        mEditText.append("\n");
        mEditText.append("\n--- Raw Data ---\n\n");
        mEditText.append(data);*/
        mEditText.setSelection(0);
    }
}
```

Before I try to merge celebrity model to my project, it works fine :/ Now, whatever picture I took, it returns error on post execute.

Comment: Hi, rann02. I'm not sure the meaning of combining different azure cognitive APIs. You just want use cognitive APIs in Android?Or any other purpose?Please post more details,thank you.

Comment: Hello @JayGong! sorry for the general question.  we're creating a mobile application for the visually impaired that could detect any objects/person within the surrounding using the device's camera with the help of computer vision API,face API and custom vision API, we are not sure how to implement the APIs together because on the documentation for the implementation in cognitive services it only shows a specific API. but not combining them together. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You need to make separate calls to each service for now.

Comment: Hello Jay gong, we are still working on it. I will give you an update on feb

Comment: @rann02 Sure. Any concern,please let me know.

Comment: @JayGong Hello again!, We're currently trying to implement an API but it returns a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $` Do you know what causes the problem?

Comment: @rann02 Which api? Would you please provide your snippet of code and error trace in your question ? Then maybe  I could know how to help you.

Comment: Hello @JayGong I am using Computer Vision API. After I capture the image the result I am getting from the Json is, "Error executing  post request received error code 400" Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: @rann02 Hi, raan02. Would you please post your snippet of code and complete error trace?

Comment: Hi @JayGong! I just edited my question. However there's no trace of error 400 on the logcat :/ what to do?

Answer (score 0):

As I know , Azure Cognitive service APIs are all independent APIs that meet different scenarios. As @Ronak said , you need to call Face, Computer Vision, and Emotion API separately for now.

You could find the `Azure Cogonitive APIs` for Android as below.

1.[Computer Vision API](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Vision-Android)

2.[Face API](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Android)

3.[Emotion API](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Emotion-Android)

Hope it helps you.